# loads of "The type or namespace name 'NamespaceExample' could not be found" errors on different machines

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, nuget-package, assembly-references

My collaborator and I have been having this problem incessantly as we try to update the project and share it back and fourth on GitHub. And yes, I've Googled and searched the forums for a couple days. Nothing...

Basically, we get a laundry list of these namespace errors even though the correct "using" statements are there and the packages appear intact. This happens each time I try to open and build the project on a different machine.

Here are some examples...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using ScatterSchool.Models;
```

and yet...

> The type or namespace name 'IOwinContext' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticationManager' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type 'IOwinContext' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Owin,
>   Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral
>
> The type 'IDataProtectionProvider' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral
>
> 'HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'GetOwinContext'
>   and no extension method 'GetOwinContext' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

etc, etc, etc...

And as far as I can tell, all these are referenced and the packages seem to be installed. Granted, I'm a newbie and could be confused. It just seems like a silly problem to have again and again and like something my Googling and struggling should have solved by now.

TY in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: How are you installing the packages and what steps do you take when you want to rectify the problem?

Comment: Are you targeting the same framework version

Comment: @kyle - it's an interesting question I'm not sure how to answer. Under project Properties, it appears this application is targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2. How do I figure out if it's "the same framework version"?

Comment: @3dd I'm basically right clicking on the solution, going to the NuGet package manager, and ensuring that all the packages I'm referencing are indeed installed... But double checking this made me notice something! The error says something about Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0 but it looks like I have Version 3.0.1! Packages.Config says it's looking for 3.0.1 too. What do I do about that error asking for 2.1?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing NuGet packages. Check your packages.conf file and make sure all your packages that declared there are installed on your destination machine. Please click on 'References' folder in 'Solution Explorer' and make sure you have all your packages registered there (no warning signs).

If you look at your packages.config file you will find that it contains package id, version and targetFramework. For instance:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

If you need to download specific version of package, you can do it by

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin -Version 2.1.0
```

Or you can update your packages to the latest by

```
Update-Package Microsoft.Owin
```

To check if there are new versions available for installed packages use:

```
Get-Package -updates
```

You can find more information about managing NuGet packages [here](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console)

Comment: Yeah they're all installed and no warning signs but I'm starting to notice that error asks for an older version than I have installed and am targeting. for example, the error says it wants me to "add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0" but I have installed and am referencing v3.0.1... How do I resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

So the weirdest thing seems to have eliminated most of the errors: I just deleted the references in Solution Explorer then re-added them, sometimes needing to browse into the file system for the project to grab the already-existing assemblies/packages (the DLL files)... Such a strange solution and hopefully not one I'll have to repeat each time I transfer machines.

Oddly, one remained and wouldn't go away. The associated using statement and reference was just System.Web and I tried 10 different ways to remove, change, update, etc... noting helped! So, I tried restarting Visual Studio (when all else fails start restarting things, right?) and somehow that got rid of the last error...

I sure learned valuable stuff from you guys and this process though...